# Problema com loop inifnito RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, hash

Estou usando esse código para ler um arquivo de texto usando o `RandomAccessFile`, caractere por caractere, e gerando uma string a cada palavra formada, para salvar numa HashMap. Eu preciso usar a `RandomAccessFile` pois eu preciso saber a posição da palavra no arquivo, por isso eu salvo no meu tipo Registro esse valor `offset = arq.getFilePointer()`

O problema é que quando eu faço a verificação no `while(arq.read() != -1)` o ponteiro do arquivo avança uma posição, de modo que eu sempre perco a primeira letra da minha palavra. Se eu tento dar um `arq.seek()` na posição anterior, eu até pego a primeira letra novamente, mas o programa fica num loop infinito.

Existe alguma outra forma de controlar quando o arquivo chega ao final sem ser usando o `arq.read()`?

```
try {
RandomAccessFile arq = new RandomAccessFile("teste.txt", "r"); 
  try{ 
    while(arq.read() != -1) {
     String palavra = "";
     offset = arq.getFilePointer();
     letra = (char)arq.read(); 
        while (letra != ' ' && letra != '\n') {
          palavra += letra;
          letra = (char)arq.read();
        }
          palavra = palavra.toLowerCase();
          System.out.println(palavra); 
             if (h.PesquisaRegistro(palavra) == null) { 
                x = new Registro(palavra, offset);
                h.Inserir(x, h.HashCode(x));
             } else {
                x = h.PesquisaRegistro(palavra);
                x.quantidade++;
                h.tabela.replace(h.PesquisaChave(palavra), x);
             }
     }       
   }catch(EOFException ex){
   }       
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia definir uma variável antes do while e armazenar o retorno do primeiro read nela.

---

Com *while*:

```
RandomAccessFile arq = new RandomAccessFile("teste.txt", "r");
int letraByte = arq.read();
while (letraByte != -1){
    String palavra = "";

    while ((char) letraByte != ' ' && (char) letraByte != '\n' && letraByte != -1) {
        palavra += (char) letraByte;
        letraByte = arq.read();
    }

    letraByte = arq.read();
    System.out.println(palavra);
}
```

---

Com *do while*:

```
RandomAccessFile arq = new RandomAccessFile("teste.txt", "r");
int letraByte;
do {
    String palavra = "";
    letraByte = arq.read();

    while ((char) letraByte != ' ' && (char) letraByte != '\n' && letraByte != -1) {
        palavra += (char) letraByte;
        letraByte = arq.read();
    }
    System.out.println(palavra);
} while (letraByte != -1);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Eu já havia feito dessa forma hoje mais cedo antes de conseguir entrar aqui. Funcionou!!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplesmente chamar arq.read() antes e no fim do while e colocar o valor em uma variável e testar essa variável. Assim você pode ler o valor depois sem andar o ponteiro do arquivo.

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito o que você quis dizer, mas vamos lá: Você disse para eu chamar o `arq.read()` antes do `while`. Ok. Aí eu já perdi a primeira letra da palavra. Se eu chamar uma vez no final também, perco mais uma letra. Se eu salvar em uma variável, toda vez que eu salvar, vou acabar "perdendo" um caractere. Desculpa, não entendi mesmo.

Comment: É pq estou no celular agora, e fica complicado de mostrar em código. Mas vc não vai perder se sempre q vc chamar arq.read() você colocar o valor lido nessa variável. Você vai ter que chamar uma vez antes do while pra ter algo pra comparar da primeira vez, e depois chamar no fim do while pra ler no próximo loop.

Comment: bom, se eu entendi direito, é fazer o que eu estou fazendo com `letra`. Estou salvando o valor do `arq.read()` nela a cada iteração, e usar esse valor como comparação?